# I can't seem to get this to work. The page doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

sorry if this is hard to read but I can't get this to work. I have been scanning the code looking for little mistakes such as missing semi colons and commas. However, I don't know if there is something I am doing completely wrong or I am just missing a little tidbit. No matter what. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

I got the program to work now! Thank you very much and sorry for the dumb question (judging from the amount of votes). Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> WEB204 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     var jsonData = {
      "rows" : [
       {
        "customer_id" : 148,
        "customer_name" : "Al's Appliance and Sport",
        "street" : "2837 Greenway",
        "city" : "Fillmore",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33336,
        "balance" : 6550,
        "credit_limit" : 7500,
        "REP_ID" : 20
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 282,
        "customer_name" : "Brookings Direct",
        "street" : "3827 Devon"
        "city" : "Grove",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33321,
        "balance" : 431,
        "credit_limit" : 10000,
        "REP_ID" : 35
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 356,
        "customer_name" : "Ferguson's",
        "street" : "382 Wildwood",
        "city" : "Northfield",
        "state" : "FL"
        "ZIP" : 33146,
        "balance" : 5785,
        "credit_limit" : 7500,
        "REP_ID" : 65
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 408,
        "customer_name" : "The Everything Shop",
        "street" : "1828 Raven",
        "city" : "Crystal",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33503,
        "balance" : 5285,
        "credit_limit" : 5000,
        "REP_ID" : 35
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 462,
        "customer_name" : "Bargains Galore",
        "street" : "3829 Central",
        "city" : "Grove",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33321,
        "balance" : 3412,
        "credit_limit" : 10000,
        "REP_ID" : 65
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 148,
        "customer_name" : "Kline's",
        "street" : "838 Ridgeland",
        "city" : "Fillmore",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33336,
        "balance" : 12762,
        "credit_limit" : 15000,
        "REP_ID" : 20
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 608,
        "customer_name" : "Johnson's Department Store",
        "street" : "372 Oxford",
        "city" : "Sheldon",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33553,
        "balance" : 2106,
        "credit_limit" : 10000,
        "REP_ID" : 65
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 687,
        "customer_name" : "Lee's Sport and Appliance",
        "street" : "282 Evergreen",
        "city" : "Altonville",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 32543,
        "balance" : 2851,
        "credit_limit" : 5000,
        "REP_ID" : 35
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 725,
        "customer_name" : "Deerfield's Four Seasons",
        "street" : "282 Columbia",
        "city" : "Sheldon",
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33553,
        "balance" : 248,
        "credit_limit" : 7500,
        "REP_ID" : 35
       },
       {
        "customer_id" : 842,
        "customer_name" : "All Season",
        "street" : "28 Lakeview",
        "city" : "Grove", 
        "state" : "FL",
        "ZIP" : 33321,
        "balance" : 8221,
        "credit_limit" : 7500,
        "REP_ID" : 20
       },
    ]
    };
    </script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("container1").html(
                "customer_id: "     + jsonData.rows[0].customer_id      + "<br/>"   +
                "customer_name: "   + jsonData.rows[0].customer_name    + "<br/>"   +
                "street: "          + jsonData.rows[0].street           + "<br/>"   +
                "city : "           + jsonData.rows[0].city             + "<br/>"   +
                "state: "           + jsonData.rows[0].state            + "<br/>"   +
                "ZIP: "             + jsonData.rows[0].ZIP              + "<br/>"   +
                "balance: "         + jsonData.rows[0].balance          + "<br/>"   +
                "credit length: "   + jsonData.rows[0].credit_limit     + "<br/>"   +
                "REP_ID: "          + jsonData.rows[0].REP_ID           + "<br/>"   +
                "<br/>" 

                );

        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container1" class="narrow"> </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the error console?

Comment: Obligatory remark: That's not JSON. It's just an array of JavaScript objects.

Comment: Missing a comma after `"street": "3827 Devon"` and `"state": "FL"`

Comment: I do not get anything in the error console @SLaks

Comment: When you say "doesn't display", do you mean you're presented with an empty page as a response?

Comment: extra comma at the end ` },
    ]`

Comment: `$("container1")` selects `<container1></container1>`. You want `$('#container1')` to select by id.

Comment: Really? I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string and
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined

Comment: Learn to lint your code http://www.jslint.com/ or http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON has some missing commas and one extra comma (at the end of the array, not all browsers complain about this). Such as:

```
"state" : "FL"
"ZIP" : 33146,
```

Checkout [JSONLint.com](http://JSONLint.com)), as well as the issues pointed out in other answers. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BjK8S/) with these issues fixed.

Comment: I tried your fixes as well. http://jsfiddle.net/3825/4czJN/4/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you need to use a hash symbol to refer to objects by id, as so

```
$("#container1").html( ... ...
   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$("#container1").html(
```

to actually select the div with that id

Comment: @LewisM. That is because your code contains *several* errors.

Comment: @meagar yes. I agree. Very sorry for that but I did get the thing working. This really helped!

Comment: @LewisM. Why did you say you didn't get errors when you obviously did?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid , several commas missing

```
{
"customer_id" : 282,
"customer_name" : "Brookings Direct",
"street" : "3827 Devon",//here
"city" : "Grove",
"state" : "FL",
"ZIP" : 33321,
"balance" : 431,
"credit_limit" : 10000,
"REP_ID" : 35
},
{
"customer_id" : 356,
"customer_name" : "Ferguson's",
"street" : "382 Wildwood",
"city" : "Northfield",
"state" : "FL",//here
"ZIP" : 33146,
"balance" : 5785,
"credit_limit" : 7500,
"REP_ID" : 65
}
```